# One to many relationship using SQFlite (Flutter)

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I was hoping someone could write or show me an example of a "One to Many" relationship in Flutter using SQFlite.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I wanted an example using Dart code. I'm a total beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it easily by using `jaguar_orm` Package

You can locate package using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_orm this url

Add this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  jaguar_orm: ^2.2.5
```

Get/update packages:

```
$ flutter packages get
```

Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:jaguar_orm/jaguar_orm.dart';
```

For details example please visit above given url.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you should use plugins if the concept is not clear.

Each POJO can be an abstract object, for this, when you create your models, making a practical example:
User -> Stationery stores.
In this case we assume that a user can have more stationery but it cannot be the other way around.
In your user, you can enter a list of stationery stores.

When you go to make a query, like a simple SELECT, you'll already find the bookstores in the User table.
This is a simple example ...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it easily by using moor Package
You can locate package using https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter this url
Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  moor_flutter: ^3.1.0
Get/update packages:

$ flutter packages get
```

Now in your Dart code, you can use:

and this tutorial will help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpWsedYMczM